# Format first values in arrays

Tags: java

I have a method which extract key values from string:

```
  public Map<String, String> extract(String input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
                .map(subString -> subString.split("="))
                .map(this::convertStringArr)
                .filter(strings -> !strings[0].isBlank())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        key -> key[0],
                        value -> value[1],
                        (val1, val2) -> val2));
    }
```

This method to convert key:

```
private String[] convertStringArr(String[] input) {
        String [] arr = new String[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[0] = convert(input[0]);
            arr[1] = input[1];
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

And method which converts incoming keys:

```
//it's not a real method, it's just imitates iteraction with database, but 100% same functionality
private String convert(String inputs) {
        switch (input) {
            case "book_author":
                return "ga:author";
            case "book_id":
                return "ga:id";
            case "book_source":
                return "ga:marketplace";
            case "book_target":
                return "";
            default:
                return input;
        }
    }
```

**My main goal is:** extract keys and values from string, convert key, filter empty keys and collect it to map.

This works, but i want to refactor `convertStringArr(String[] input)` method, without creating new array, for loops, etc. How can I do it?

Remember this functionality: String splits into arrays, each array always contains 2 values, [0] - is always a key, [1] - is always a value. I need to convert key before collecting it to map, because without it i will have a map with empty key (thats why i have a filter after map).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
return Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
    .map(subString -> subString.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> convert(key[0]), // call convert here!
        value -> value[1],
        (val1, val2) -> val2
    ));
```

A slight problem with this is that this will leave you with a map that has a `""` key. You might want to remove that:

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
    .map(subString -> subString.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> convert(key[0]),
        value -> value[1],
        (val1, val2) -> val2
    ));
map.remove("");
return map;
```

Or if you don't mind calling `convert` multiple times, use `filter`

```
return Arrays.stream(input.split("&"))
    .map(subString -> subString.split("="))
    .filter(x -> !convert(x[0]).isBlank())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        key -> convert(key[0]),
        value -> value[1],
        (val1, val2) -> val2
    ));
```

Anyway, given that you are returning a map, the calling code probably won't try to access the `""` key anyway, so you probably don't need to remove it either way.